# Numpy cannot `vectorize` a function

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I want to apply this simple function to numpy arrays ***fast***:

```
def f (x):
    return max(0,1-abs(x))
```

Just for clarity's sake, here is the plot:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.linspace(start=-4,stop=4, num=100)
plt.plot(x, list(map(f,x)))
```

[image: function plot]

However, `np.vectorize(f)(x)` returns a vector of 0

Yes, I know that

> The [`vectorize`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) function is provided primarily for convenience, not for performance. The implementation is essentially a `for` loop.

but it should at least return a correct value, no?

PS. I managed to vectorize `f` by hand:

```
def f (x):
    z = np.zeros(x.shape)
    return np.fmax(z,1-np.abs(x), out=z)
```

Comment: This seems to be due to the return type being assume dto be int64.

Comment: `np.fmax(0,1-np.abs(x))` is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `np.vectorize` is inferring the return type as an integer dtype. Note this part from the docs:

> The data type of the output of vectorized is determined by calling the
> function with the first element of the input. This can be avoided by
> specifying the otypes argument.

In your case, the output of `max(0, 1 - abs(-4.))` is an `int` object, `0`. You could either change your function to use a `float`, or specify the `outypes` parameter explicitly:

```
np.vectorize(f, otypes=[np.float64])(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

The return type of max function is taken to be int because you used 0 instead of 0.0. Using

```py
def f(x):
    return max(0.0,1.0-abs(x))
```

Will give the right answer